# bash: ping: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, path

My shell can't find ping.

```
$ ping
-bash: ping: command not found
$ uname -r
14.5.0
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/Users/alex/.cabal/bin
$ which ping
$
```

However, `man ping` works and displays the manual page for ping.

Is it named something different on OSX?  Or is there an alternative I should use?

Comment: You are missing `/sbin` in your PATH variable.

Comment: If you run `/usr/libexec/path_helper` does the path change? (and is ping found)

Comment: I'm going to point this to a canonical "my path variable is messed up" and if you don't find a solution there, let's edit the body of the question to explain which answer was rejected and get some more detail...

Comment: @bmike yep, that helped, as did fd0's suggstions about `/sbin`.  Shall I delete the question?

Comment: @hoosierEE No - we actually love "closed questions" since someone searching google might use your words as opposed to the words on the duplicate. Also - if you find an edge case, it's better to reopen this after an edit is made to the post.